# How can I share or send a radio program I've recorded from the Tune in radio app on my iPhone 5s?

Tags: iphone

I recorded an AM radio interview via the Tune In radio app on my iPhone 5S.  I would like to share the recorded program by sending the link, if there is one, to someone else by email or text.  Is this possible?

Comment: How did you record it?

Comment: See question and answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Your supposed to be able to share recordings via their app but I think there is bug that prevents that from happening. I have the TuneIn Radio Pro app and recorded a bit of a station. Then I tried to share it by clicking on my recording and then tapping the little share button (the only options it gives are send via email, text message or G+) and it gave me a url like this: recording://1414797133.74747 I was unable to open this link when shared to friends with the app, or even open it myself. This was tested with version 6.5 of their app.

Comment: Yes, this is the same experience I had as well.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do it, is by first record the program in your computer using a program like cool edit pro  or Adobe.. after you have it as mp3 then u can share it.. 
otherwise you will be sharing the tune in pro app only

Comment: The "Analogue Hole" - what a pity those scabby fools couldn't actually make it easier.